# How to fix a natbib apacite citation when it displays the wrong year?

Tags: natbib, apacite

I would like to cite something so that it comes up as

> *Something important has been shown (author, 2000; 2006).*

Although, I do not care about the separator between 2000 and 2006 (the semicolon was just used as an example).

When I compile my document, I get

> *Something important has been shown (author, 2000, 0).*

Citation1 is an article (published in 2000) and citation2 is a book (published in 2006).

The code I currently use looks approximately like this:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@book{doyle2006making,
  title={Making war and building peace: United Nations peace operations},
  author={Doyle, Michael W and Sambanis, Nicholas},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Princeton University Press}
}

@article{doyle2000international,
  title={International peacebuilding: A theoretical and quantitative analysis},
  author={Doyle, Michael W and Sambanis, Nicholas},
  journal={American political science review},
  volume={94},
  number={4},
  pages={779--801},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{graphicx, floatpag, caption}
\newcommand\textlcsc[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}



\begin{document}

Something important has been shown \citep{citation1, citation2}.

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please share the `.bib` entries with us and extend the code in the question here such that it loads the `.bib` file and a bibliography style. The following naive extension of your code show the expected output "(Smith, 2000, 2006)" for me https://gist.github.com/moewew/3387d93db36e34327173d41e87aa6c7d, so there *must* be something else going on at your end.

Comment: Don't use the `apalike` bibliography style with `apacite`. You *must* use the `apacite` bibliography style with it.

Comment: That suggestion fixed it. If you post it, I can accept it as the right answer.

Comment: Alan has already given the answer and it has nothing to do with the issue at hand, but `\bibliography` takes the file name *without* extension, so `\bibliography{bibliography.bib}` should be `\bibliography{bibliography}`. Strictly speaking `\bibliography{bibliography.bib}` is a syntax error, but some TeX systems are more lenient and still accept it (my MikTeX isn't and throws an error: `I couldn't open database file bibliography.bib.bib`). Note also that the `.bib` files in the MWE don't match (`\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}` but `\bibliography{bibliography.bib}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apacite` package can only be used with the `apacite` bibliography style, and you are loading the `apalike` style, so to fix your problem you need to use:

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

As moewe notes in the comments, the syntax of the `\bibliography` command requires a `.bib` file name *without* the `.bib` extension, and you're just lucky if this works. So if your `.bib` file is named `mybib.bib` you should use:

```
\bibliography{mybib}
```